# C# Lock Threading Issue

Tags: c#, multithreading, dictionary, locks

The task here is quite simple (or so I thought...). I want to fill a queue with methods to be executed (all of which will return an object result), and then I want to have some arbitrary number of threads pull from this queue, execute the methods, and add the results to some other collection (a dictionary in this case) which will be returned when all the work is complete. A main method will be called in the main thread which will start the processing and should block until all the threads are finished doing whatever they're doing and return the collection with the results. So I put together this class:

```
public class BackgroundWorkManager
{
    public delegate object ThreadTask();

    private Thread[] workers;
    private ManualResetEvent workerThreadMre;
    private ManualResetEvent mainThreadMre;
    private Queue<WorkItem> workQueue;
    private Dictionary<string, object> results;
    private object writeLock;
    private int activeTasks;

    private struct WorkItem
    {
        public string name;
        public ThreadTask task;

        public WorkItem(string name, ThreadTask task)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.task = task;
        }
    }

    private void workMethod()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            workerThreadMre.WaitOne();

            WorkItem task;

            lock (workQueue)
            {
                if (workQueue.Count == 0)
                {
                    workerThreadMre.Reset();
                    continue;
                }

                task = workQueue.Dequeue();
            }

            object result = task.task();

            lock (writeLock)
            {
                results.Add(task.name, result);
                activeTasks--;

                if (activeTasks == 0)
                    mainThreadMre.Set();
            }
        }
    }

    public BackgroundWorkManager()
    {
        workers = new Thread[Environment.ProcessorCount];
        workerThreadMre = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        mainThreadMre = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        workQueue = new Queue<WorkItem>();
        writeLock = new object();
        activeTasks = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < Environment.ProcessorCount; i++)
        {
            workers[i] = new Thread(workMethod);
            workers[i].Priority = ThreadPriority.Highest;
            workers[i].Start();
        }
    }

    public void addTask(string name, ThreadTask task)
    {
        workQueue.Enqueue(new WorkItem(name, task));
    }

    public Dictionary<string, object> process()
    {
        results = new Dictionary<string, object>();

        activeTasks = workQueue.Count;

        mainThreadMre.Reset();
        workerThreadMre.Set();
        mainThreadMre.WaitOne();
        workerThreadMre.Reset();

        return results;
    }
}
```

This works fine if I used the object once to process a queue of methods, but if I try something like this

```
BackgroundWorkManager manager = new BackgroundWorkManager();

for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    manager.addTask("result1", (BackgroundWorkManager.ThreadTask)delegate
    {
        return (object)(1);
    });

    manager.process();
}
```

Things break. I either get deadlocking or I get an exception saying the dictionary that I'm writing the results to already contains the key (yet the Visual Studio Debugger says it's empty). Adding a 'Thread.Sleep(1)' to the work method seems to fix it, which is bizarre. This is my first time working with threads, so I'm not sure if I'm horribly abusing locks, or what. If anyone could provide some insight into what I'm doing wrong, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're adding multiple tasks with the same name. Why are you surprised to get `Dictionary already contains the key`? Also, it should be pretty easy to meet your requirements using PLINQ. Simple `AsParallel` + `ToDictionary` should make the trick, without locking or anything.

Comment: Because the process method creates a new dictionary instance, which results are then added to.

Comment: The fact that it creates new dictionary doesn't make any difference. You're assigning it to field in the class that's being used by multiple different threads, so it's fairly likely multiple threads will write to the same instance of `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`.

Comment: Right, but the purpose of the lock is that they won't. Only one thread should be able to grab the delegate and execute it and the result should be added the dictionary, at which point the process method returns the dictionary. The process method is blocking.

Comment: This is the classic producer-consumer pattern. I suggest you look into [`BlockingCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`TPL Dataflow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of trying to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

version with Parallel class:

```
List<Func<object>> actions = new List<Func<object>>();

actions.Add(delegate { return (object)(1); });
actions.Add(delegate { return (object)(1); });
actions.Add(delegate { return (object)(1); });

Dictionary<string, object> results = new Dictionary<string,object>();

Parallel.ForEach(actions,(f)=> {
    lock (results)
    {
        results.Add(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), f());
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of options of how to work with the *producer-consumer pattern*. For example, you can simplify your code drastically by using an `ActionBlock<T>` (which is part of [`TPL Dataflow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)):

```
var concurrentDictionary = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, object>();

ActionBlock<Func<object>> actionBlock = new ActionBlock<Func<object>>((func) => 
{
    var obj = func();
    concurrentDictionary.AddOrUpdate("someKey", obj, (s,o) => o);
}, new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism =
                                       Environment.ProcessorCount });
```

And then simply post your delegates:

```
foreach (var task in tasks)
{
    actionBlock.Post(() => (object) 1);
}
```

Comment: I didn't realize how much of this .NET can do for you. Thanks.